# Confluent Kafka: Setting Retention.ms for an individual topic not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-python

I'm using confluent Kafka in my project where the messages sent to a particular topic need to be deleted after a retention time. So I set retention.ms for the individual topics but it's not working (Still I can see messages after its retention time)

I have browsed most of the stack questions but still, I can't able to find a proper reason/ solution for Kafka retention.ms not working problem.

**I followed the below steps to create and set retention time in ms.**

1. Created a topic say. 'user_status'
2. updated its retention.ms time by following below code

   ```
    from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, ConfigResource, NewTopic, NewPartitions
    from confluent_kafka import Producer, Consumer, KafkaError, KafkaException

    topic_config = ConfigResource('topic', 'user_status')
    topic_config.set_config('retention.ms', '5000')
    admin.alter_configs([topic_config])
   ```
3. Send message from producer end.
4. waited for 6000 ms time.
5. Tried to receive the message from particular topic. But I received the message, And still the message was not deleted by retention policy.

**Note:**
I ensured below
After updating retention.ms I verified the same has been updated in kafka topic information (Topic describe).

Also, I updated server.properties with the log.retention.check.interval.ms=1 ms and restarted Kafka service after I updated the properties file.

**what I expect from the above question**

I want to set a retention.ms to an individual topic and the message passing that time should be automatically deleted as defined in Kafka policy.

**what happening now with my current code.**
The messages are still received by consumer even after retention.ms time.